# Cisco Catalyst 2960 X MAC access list

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, cisco-catalyst, security

I am using a MAC access list on this switch, so I go about it by first creating the MAC access list:

```
#conf t
#mac access-list extended aclname
# permit host XXXX.XXXX.XXXX any
```

Then, I tie this list to all/one port:

```
#conf t
#interface gigabit 1/0/Y
# mac access-group aclname in
```

So, any traffic coming towards port Y gets checked against the MAC access list,  to check if the source is allowed to enter.

Then i do a `#clear mac address-table dynamic`

I have done this to many site offices, but there is this particular site which has about 80+ devices that is driving me crazy, this site has a larger number of devices than the rest sites. So everytime i add a mac, another device gets disconnected.

I guess my question is: Is there any limitation on this access list? How many? How do you propose I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are running out of the limited TCAM space. You could change the SDM. If you are not using this as a layer-3 switch with routing, you could use the `sdm prefer access` command to increase the TCAM space for ACLs. This command requires you to reload the switch for it to take effect.

This seems like a lot of work for little to no gain. It is very simple to spoof or change a MAC address in a host. Trying to restrict access based on MAC addresses is a fool's game. Anyone could waltz in there and clone a MAC address for his device to connect to your network. There are much better ways to do this. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22247/8499), its comments, and its answers. There are also other question and answer on this site if you search.

Comment: Thank you Ron, this is what i am looking for! I wonder if sdm prefer access is better than sdm prefer vlan? What do you think?

Comment: Either should give you more TCAM space. It depends on your needs.

Comment: You have been extremely helpful, thank you very much good human being