# Rogue Wireless Scanning

Tags: wireless, security, ad-hoc-wireless, rogue

Is Rogue Wireless scanning required for a "wired" network? The organization does not have a wireless environment. I am just curious the reasons behind conducting the scan and what is the risk if the organization has other tools that monitor the network and detects when a new device connects?

Comment: Do you have vulnerable places that rogue devices can be connected? what are the monitoring tools you use? There are other steps to take. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22247/8499) and answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those "it depends" questions.  It depends on

1. How much of a risk rogue APs are to the organization.
2. How well you can detect unknown devices being connected to the
   network.

Only you can answer this question for your organization.